# New to C++, Visual Studios Professional 2013 can't run projects made in Visual Studios C++ Express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

And now, the projects that I tried to open and run (very basic projects - little more than learning programs like hello world type programs) in VS 2013 can't be opened and run in VS Express 2010 either. Everything is licensed properly.

In fact, when I open my program in VS Express 2010 now, it underlines basic things in the header like "iostream" in red, and doesn't recognize them.

If I build a new project in either, it's just fine. But I can't get projects to work across one from the other, and if I do try, it does some rebuild, and then those projects won't work in either.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that happened with me when I tried to use a project of *gmap.net (winforms)* that I made with *Visual Studio 2013* into the new version of *VS 2015*.

Into my case, I could see all the code I had made in C#, but I couldn't change the design of the project and I think that it will be impossible so I have been working with both.

But in your case, if you want just open the code, you should find the file with `.csproj` or something similar to this and do not open the project by the `.sln` if you know what I mean.

Doing this it will work just fine. And of course, don't forget that you should import all extensions to your new VS.

## PS:

*I found a nice explation of your problem [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747(v=vs.120).aspx) at the Visual Studio website.* ***And this was the answer:***

> *If you allow Visual Studio to update the project automatically, you can open it in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1.*